# MVC how to set Navigation Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am having issues with making the navigation properties correctly since I get the error

> The Foreign key component ID is not a declared property on type Administrator.

My model basically consists of a base class `User` which has two derived classes `Administrator` and `Common` user. I believe this is a one to many relation since there can be multiple common and administrator users.

My classes look like this:

```
    [Table("User")]
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Common> CommonUsers { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Administrator> Administrators { get; set;}
    }

    public class Administrator : Usuario
    {
        [ForeignKey("User")]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }

    public class Common : Usuario
    {
        [ForeignKey("User")]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

I set the foiregn key on both ID attributes in the derived classes to reference the User ID which is the primary key for the table.
Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: *I believe this is a one to many relation* No, it's inheritance and you should remove the ID properties from the sub classes entirely.

Comment: @GertArnold I added them before because I got a similar error, but now I could create the scaffolding item correctly. Thank you very very much. I spent hours on this :) . You can make it an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: @GertArnold Also, when I create the database from this model, how will it create a foreign key for this derived classes in the database?.

Comment: A foreign key to what? By default all types will be in one table with a discriminator column. (TPH).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semantically your construction

```
public virtual ICollection<Common> CommonUsers { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Administrator> Administrators { get; set;}
```

mean that a single `user` can be multiple `Administrators` and each `Administrator` can be assigned to a single user.

```
public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

From the logic explained it should vise versa.

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }

    //public virtual ICollection<Common> CommonUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual Administrator Administrators { get; set;}
}

public class Administrator : Usuario
{
    //Primary key is required but not defined
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    //same admin role applies to many users
    public virtual ICollection<User> User { get; set; }
}
```

Also note that class name `User` may shadow / conflict with `System.Security.Principal.User`

Most probably you mean

```
public class Usuario // User
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }

    //public virtual ICollection<Common> CommonUsers { get; set; }
    //public virtual ICollection<Administrator> Administrators { get; set;}

    //define 1-to-1(0)
    public virtual Common CommonUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual Administrator Administrators { get; set;}
}

public class Administrator : Usuario
{
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I see, would you recommend that I take the 1 to 1 approach in all three classes or 1 to * on the derived classes as you commented above?.

Comment: Remove `CommonUsers` class and apply some default settings to users who are not `Admin`